# bbs forum reply post sequence random ,I want it sequence order by datetime desc

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, forum, reply

I made a forum using asp.net ,when I tried to reply my post,I found a strange question. if you reply 10 times,you will find the sequence of my replying is random,not order by the datetime,so how to solve it?
I can not show the code because this is the project of company ,sorry.It is a secret.
who can give me the right thinking method?Just tell me how to do.and why it is random.
thanks a lot.

Comment: who knows the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While displaying replies, sort the replies by posted date ..